# Laravel: No http in my url

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5.4

If I want to access my site `http://www.myawesomesite.com` it simply rewrites to `www.myawesomesite.com`.

I host my site on my VPS and I not tinkered my `.htaccess`.

How to tell the rewrite engine, that I want to see the http allways if I'm on that VPS? (and not on local)

My `.htaccess` file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
 </IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can't. Thats the browsers decision to show or hide it.

Comment: The HTTP is there, the browser just decides to not show it (as it's meaningless noise to the end user)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you :)